# How can I run regular one-hour sessions of D&D?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, group-dynamics, time

I had an idea while talking to some co-workers today. I asked them if they'd be interested in starting a game that we could play during our lunch hours. My idea is that we'd spend at least one hour a week when we're all free and slowly play out our story before going back to work.

The only real question that came up was "How?" Personally, I'm okay with these kinda micro sessions, but the others have their doubts. So I'm wondering if anyone else has run a similar campaign; where you play in smaller bursts.

**What's a good way to go about this? Is there a particular version that is more suited for this kind of gameplay?**

Comment: Suggest you drop by [RPG.SE chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=rpg.stackexchange.com).  That's a good place to brainstorm stuff like this.

Comment: Related: [Is it practical to run a weekly lunch-hour game of D&D with my coworkers?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/5123/1204)

Comment: @doppelgreener Thanks for the link. That didn't show up anywhere in my related list.

Comment: Are you set on some variant of Dungeons and Dragons, or are you open to other systems?

Comment: Other systems are fine